# Получить массив тех отрывков, которые пользователь проиграл

Tags: javascript, html

```
console.log(audio.played);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges

Читаю, не понимаю. Необходимо по окончанию воспроизведения получить все те отрывки, что пользователь проиграл. Допустим аудио, продолжительность которого 10 сек, пользователь прослушал только первые 2 секунды и с 5 по 8 секунду.

Собственно, как можно получить массив, в котором будет дочерние массивы, отрезки, в которых будет время старта и время окончания?

```js
    cl.onclick = _ => {
        video[video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
        if(video.played.length)
            console.log(video.played);
    }
```

```html
<video id=video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" width="300" controls></video><br /><br />
<div id=cl>Click</div>
```

Comment: "Читаю, не понимаю" - это у меня такая отмазка была в универе/школе :) Что именно не понятно, что вы пробовали из этой документации и у вас не получилось?) Где попыткаи решения?)

Comment: К примеру, this.v.played.start(1), получаю ошибку. По идеи должно показать время старта первого отрезка?

Comment: Кодом поделитесь пожалуйста. Никто вам не сможет сказать откуда у вас эта ошибка и тем более что вы не говорите что за ошибка вообще? Мы не видим и не знаем ничего о вашем коде. Потому прошу вас поделиться своим МИНИМАЛЬНЫМ воспроизводимым кодом, где будет работа только с аудио связанные с получением отрезков времени, которые вам нужны

Comment: Добавил пример, получаем некий массив. Но как к примеру из первого вытащить тайм старта и окончания?

Comment: К сожалению нигде не видно попытки повторить [код из документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges#%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_timeranges) для получения отрезков времени

Answer (score 0):

Эта статья не подходит для решения, т к свойство **video.buffered()** показывает отрывки, которые были предзагружены, а не те, что пользователь проиграл. А предзагрузка (буферизация) всегда происходит с небольшим запасом.
Плюс ещё отрывки таким образом создаются даже если не воспроизводить, а только ставить курсор в определённое место или перемещать ползунок. Ещё они могут неожиданно между собой объединяться. Так что вот какой ряд недостатков.

По настоящему создать массив из проигранных отрывков можно следующим кодом:

```html
<video id=video width=300 src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" controls></video><br /><br />
<canvas id=canvas height=50 style="border-style: solid"></canvas><br /><br />
<script>
canvas.width = 300; // ширина прогрессбара
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
video.ontimeupdate = () => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(drawing(video.currentTime), 0, 1, 25);
}
let array = [];
video.onplay = () => start = video.currentTime;
video.onpause = () => {
    end = video.currentTime;
    console.log("start = " + start.toFixed(2) + "; end = " + end.toFixed(2));
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(drawing(start), 25, drawing(end - start), 25);
    array.push([start, end]);
}
function drawing(e){return e / video.duration * canvas.width};
</script>
```

Верхняя полоса на канвасе отображает проигранные фрагменты файла в реальном времени, нижняя отображает добавляемые в массив отрывки в момент нажатия на паузу и не реагирует на перемещение ползунка без воспроизведения. Работает одинаково с тегами аудио и видео.

После прочтения мной упомянутой документации **buffered()** у меня в голове не укладывается, сколько ошибок там сделано. В первом примере после каждого срабатывания **seek** (выбор места воспроизведения на плеере) циклом выводятся все накопленные до этого отрывки, включая последний. (даже страница от этого виснет) Вместо того, чтобы столько раз перерисовывать одно и то же, достаточно выводить на канвас только последний отрезок:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var myAudio = document.getElementById('my-audio');
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
    var context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'lightgray';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.strokeStyle = 'white';
    var inc = myCanvas.width / myAudio.duration;

    // отображение TimeRanges
    myAudio.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
        var current = myAudio.buffered.length - 1;
        var startX = myAudio.buffered.start(current) * inc;
        var endX = myAudio.buffered.end(current) * inc;
        var width = endX - startX;
        context.fillRect(startX, 0, width, myCanvas.height);
    });
}
```

Во втором примере ещё похлеще: вместо вывода на канвас отрывков, таким же циклом просто передёргивается ширина одной и той же полосы, отображающей буферизацию. Так как это происходит быстро, после этого остаётся видеть полосу с зафиксированной шириной, которая соответствует концу последнего отрывка:

```
  myAudio.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var duration =  myAudio.duration;
      for (var i = 0; i < myAudio.buffered.length; i++) {
            if (myAudio.buffered.start(myAudio.buffered.length - 1 - i) < myAudio.currentTime) {
                document.getElementById("buffered-amount").style.width = (myAudio.buffered.end(myAudio.buffered.length - 1 - i) / duration) * 100 + "%";
                break;
            }
        }
   });
```

И зачем нужны аж два контейнера, отображающие продолжительность аудиофайла? (с классами **buffered** и **progress**) Такое ощущение, что эти примеры писал кто-то пьяный.